# Popover position incorrect in tableviewcell button

Tags: swift, swift2, popover, uitableview

When running my popover, the code is displayed at the top left instead of displaying in the same position of the clicked icon, is there something I can change to correct the position?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you had set your aView's `CGRect` to both `x` and `y` to 0.

If you are doing it programatically, you might have to know the position where you want your view to be, or you can even set like below, to make your view start at most right of your screen (X = 0), and same row with your button's Y

```
CGRect(x:0 ,y: yourButton.frame.minY , width:self.view.frame.width,height:180)
```

Comment: Hello, even after changing the view of the position has not changed, remaining at the top left.
I think I need to call in some way the popover the cell that possess the clicked button.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even after your x is not set to 0?